# Using environment variable (get its value from awk command) as a condition in while

Tags: linux, shell, awk, while-loop, environment-variables

I use awk in the environment variable:

```
 NUMBER_OF_PORTS=`awk /^"number of ports:"/'{print $4}' Config_input.txt`
```

which returns the value `2`. 
I try to use this variable in a while loop:

```
i=1     
while (("$i" <= "$NUMBER_OF_PORTS")); do          
   echo "hello hello $i"  
   i=$(( $i+1 ))  
done
```

I receive the following error:

> -bash: ((: 1 <= : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= ")

How can I use the variable as integer and solve this problem?

**EDIT**
even if I try to do simple operation like:

> let cc=$NUMBER_OF_PORTS+0

it does not work. It is something with the fact that the variable holds the awk command. If I set cc=5 and try to implement the while with $cc it works fine.

**Example code**

```
 echo $NUMBER_OF_PORTS  
 #i=1  
 #echo $i  
 for (( i = 1; i < ${NUMBER_OF_PORTS}; i += 1 ));  
 do  
       echo "hello hello $i"  
 done
```

the output is:

> $ run_auto_config
>   2
>   1
>   : integer expression expected

Comment: What's in your `Config_input.txt`?

Comment: The Config_input file holds parametrs related to my networks. the awk command has only one match in this file and the value it return to NUMBER_OF_PORTS is 2

Comment: NUMBER_OF_PORTS is not an environment variable; it is simply a variable.  It only becomes an environment variable if you export it.

Comment: I know, but its totally irrelevant to the question. The same outcome for variable and environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUMBER_OF_PORTS` is empty. This gives me the same error:

```
i=1
NUMBER_OF_PORTS=""
while (("$i" <= "$NUMBER_OF_PORTS")); do
  echo "hello hello $i"
  i=$(( $i+1 ))
done
```

Your awk command looks very awkward. Try this:

```
NUMBER_OF_PORTS=$(awk '/^number of ports:/ {print $4}' Config_input.txt)
```

Are you sure the string "number of ports:" appears in your text file? Is there a space after the colon?

A couple of comments about your while-loop: `((...))` is arithmetic evaluation, so you don't need strings in there. Also, bare variable names (without the `$`) is ok, so you can write a bit more elegantly:

```
while (( i <= NUMBER_OF_PORTS )); do
  echo "hello hello $i"
  (( i++ ))
done
```

---

**Update:** Based on your comment, try this:

```
NUMBER_OF_PORTS=$(awk -v RS='\r\n' '/^number of ports:/ {print $4}' Config_input.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the awk command. the variable is not empty. This is the first thing I checked. please see my edited question for the code and the output. I mistakely didn't include the awk command, but trust me, its there.

Comment: @amigal, what does this show: `printf "%s" "$NUMBER_OF_PORTS" | od -c` -- I'm thinking there's a carriage return in there. Do you need to use `dos2unix` on your config file?

Comment: @amigal, see my update. Did the text get created on windows and transferred to linux?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works and yes, the file was created on windows. Can you please explain why the echo $NUMBER_OF_PORTS gave me the correct answer?

Comment: @amigal, because the "\r" character is a carriage return, and it's just printed as whitespace: you can't "see" it.

Answer (score 0):

change your while line to:

```
 while [ $i -le $NUMBER_OF_PORTS ]; do
```

then try

Comment: It doesn't help. it returns the following error: ": integer expression expected"

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace the `while` loop by a `for` loop:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= ${NUMBER_OF_PORTS}; i += 1 ));
do
    echo "hello hello $i"
done
```

Comment: What does not help? Can you please give the full error message? Can you please include the value of `NUMBER_OF_PORTS` (is it possible that NUMBER_OF_PORTS is not a valid number?)?

Comment: I will edit my question in a minute with the code and the result